# How can I count and ascend vowels from a phrases list in python 3?

Tags: python

In the list, `phrase`, given below I want to print the most frequently used vowels in an ascending order.

I have written this code below but I can't figure out how to count the vowels and print them in ascending order.

I am not sure about `len` and think that the code needs to be changed, with the addition of ascending.

```
phrase= ['world','good','question']
def phrase():
    vowels = ('a','u','i','o','e')
    count=0
    for i in range(0,len(phrase)):
        if phrase[i]==vowels[i]:
            count=count+1
            print (count)
phrase()
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to use [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter); it'll do the counting for you:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_vowels(phrase):
    vowel_counts = Counter()
    vowels = set('auioe')

    for word in phrase:
        vowel_counts.update(c for c in word if c in vowels)

    for vowel, count in vowel_counts.most_common():
        print '{}: {}'.format(vowel, count)
```

I used a `set()` for the vowels, as that makes for faster membership (`in`) testing.

Note that you *cannot* name your function and your list the same; `phrase()` replaced the list `phrase`. Name the function something different.

Demo:

```
>>> count_vowels(['world','good','question'])
o: 4
i: 1
e: 1
u: 1
>>> count_vowels('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'.split())
e: 4
o: 4
u: 2
i: 1
a: 1
```

Comment: I received an error when I write this: from colletions import counter
and the error is this: ImportError: No module named 'colletions'

Comment: @SN: Check the spelling carefully. It is `collections`, not `colletions` (missing `c`). And it is `Counter` with an *uppercase* `C`.

Answer (score 0):

there is a build in thing for this. called `count`

i think you want something like this:

```
def countVowels(word): # Where word is a string
    counted = {'a':0,'e':0,'i':0,'o':0,'u':0} #dictionary to store counts in
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'] # this line could also be vowels = counted.keys()...lol
    for letter in word:
         for vowel in vowels:
              counted[vowel] = word.count(vowel)
    return counted
```

if you want to iterate this over a list... just do

```
for word in listOfWords:
    print word , countVowels(item)
```

what i find myself often doing, is when i need a bunch of things done to a list, i make sure that i can do it perfectly to one example... Then i slap them in a list and strap a for loop on it.